# Crystal Reports Repetir Cabeçalho Na Próxima Página

Tags: crystal-reports

Boa noite.

Tenho um report confeccionado na seguinte estrutura:

> GroupHeader1: Cidade ( Agrupando por cidade e com a opção Manter Cabeçalho na Próxima Página marcado)
>
> GroupHeader2: Pessoa ( Agrupando por Pessoa e com a opção Manter Conjunto de Dados Juntos marcada)
>
> GroupFooter1: Suppressed
>
> GroupFooter2: Suppressed

Até aí tudo bem, tendo em vista que, quando realizo a impressão do relatório ele traz a seguinte configuração (exemplo):

```
SÃO PAULO
======================
Informações da Pessoa1
======================
Informações da Pessoa2
======================
Informações da Pessoa3
======================

RIO DE JANEIRO
======================
Informações da Pessoa4
======================
Informações da Pessoa5
======================
```

O grande problema é que dependendo do volume de dados ele não realiza a quebra do header cidade, como gostaria que fizesse, resultando na seguinte impressão:

Página 1:

```
SÃO PAULO
======================
Pessoa1
======================
Pessoa2
======================
Pessoa3
======================
Pessoa4
======================

RIO DE JANEIRO
======================
```

Página 2:

```
RIO DE JANEIRO
======================
Pessoa5
======================
Pessoa6
======================
```

Como podem ver, a pessoa 5 não cabe na página, mas mesmo assim ele imprime RIO DE JANEIRO na página 1 e depois novamente na página 2, agora com a Pessoa5.

O que eu quero que aconteça é que RIO DE JANEIRO não seja impresso na página 1 caso não haja espaço para imprimir ao menos uma pessoa junto. Nesse caso ele só apareceria na próxima página.

Além disso, caso haja espaço para imprimir ao menos uma pessoa, ele imprimiria RIO DE JANEIRO na primeira página junto com a primeira pessoa e RIO DE JANEIRO novamente na segunda página, mas agora com as informações da próxima pessoa.

Tentei corrigir isso com a opção Manter Conjunto de Dados Juntos marcada também para o GroupHeader1, mas ele efetua page break, o que não é o esperado.

Alguma ideia de como proceder?

Abraço!

Comment: Uso , botão direito no grupo , alterar grupo , aba opções , manter grupo em conjunto

Comment: Motta, grato pelo retorno! O grande problema é que com essa opção, ele vai entender o como um bloco único e realizar a quebra da página.

Comment: tem tb a opção de repetir o cabeçalho em cada página , seria isto ?